# Alamofire not hit the API and set the header

Tags: swift3

I am using Alamofire for api call. but not hit the API. And also how to set the header in Alamofire.

```
func signupApiASyncPostCall(_ url:String, params:[String: AnyObject]?, success successBlock :@escaping apiSuccess,failure failureBlock :@escaping apiFailure) {

    let Auth_header    = ["Content-Type" : "application/json",                                                                  "application/json" : "Accept"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: Auth_header)       
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("\(response.request?.url)")  // original URL request
            //print(response.response) // URL response
            //print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if response.result.isSuccess {
                successBlock(response.result.value as? NSDictionary)
                print(successBlock(response.result.value as? NSDictionary))
            } else {
                let httpError: NSError = response.result.error! as NSError
                let statusCode = httpError.code
                let error:NSDictionary = ["error" : httpError,"statusCode" : String(statusCode)]
                failureBlock(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not hit the API"? If you want to set the header then create the request with a URLRequest instead of a URL.

Comment: API is not hit , Its show header error from server , I dont know how to set the header Please suggest me.

Comment: To set the header use a URLRequest instead of just a String in the request. The header is contained in the URLRequest. Also... if you are getting an error from the API then the API IS being hit.